# How to make php file using Yii2 framework to be more structural?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to put **Description's button** in php file like this:

[image]

But when I tried to make code like this,

```
<?php

    use miloschuman\highcharts\HighchartsAsset;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    HighchartsAsset::register($this)->withScripts(['modules/exporting', 'modules/drilldown']);  
    $this->title = 'Highcharts Test';
?>


<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Description', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
<div id="my-chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



<!-- jenis kelamin magister -->    
    <?php $this->registerJs("
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Jumlah Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan Jenis Kelamin'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: $tahundaftarpelamar
    },
    yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Jumlah'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
    credits:
    {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'Laki-Laki',
            data: $lakilakipelamar
        }, {
            name: 'Perempuan',
            data: $perempuanpelamar
        },
        {
            name: 'Tidak Diketahui',
            data: $tidakdiketahuipelamar
        }]
});
});
")?>
</div>
</div>

<!-- usia -->

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Description', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
<div id="my-chart2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<?php $this->registerJs("
   $(function () {
    $('#my-chart2').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Jumlah Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan Usia'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: $tahundaftarusiapelamar
    },
    yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Jumlah'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
    credits:
    {
        enabled: false
    },
            series: [{
                name: '<25',
                data: $usialess25pelamar
            }, {
                name: '25-29',
                data: $usiabetw25pelamar
            },
            {
                name: '30-34',
                data: $usiabetw30pelamar
            },
            {
                name: '35-39',
                data: $usiabetw35pelamar
            },
            {
                name: '40-44',
                data: $usiabetw40pelamar
            },
            {
                name: '45-49',
                data: $usiabetw45pelamar
            },
            {
                name: '>=50',
                data: $usiamore50pelamar
            },
            {
                name: 'Tidak Lengkap',
                data: $usianotcompletepelamar
            }       
            ]
        });
    });
    ")?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

the result was like this:

[image]

What may I do so that I can get the result like the first picture? Thank you in advance

Comment: HTML tags are incorrect

Comment: could you please help me to correct them? @andrzej1_1

Comment: I see you deleted one wrong tag. There is still problem that there are unclosed ones. Also you are using row in row which is wrong in bootstrap grid system.

Comment: so what may I do to make them correct? When I edited the codes still get the wrong result @andrzej1_1

Comment: What about something like this: https://pastebin.com/uV5LRzpY

Comment: yes, it works. Thankyou ;) @andrzej1_1